# Separating a string through character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string with some blank space in the format

*My name is ______ I live at ______.*

blank is represented through 6 underscores. I want to separate my string using these underscores in a way that the first index of array contains string *My name is* and the second index contains *I live at*. Also while displaying on front end I want these underscores to be replaced by disabled input fields.

How can i do this using javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` with the regex `/_{6}/g` to convert it into array.

```js
var string = "My name is ______ I live at ______.";

var arr = string.split(/_{6}/g);

console.log(arr);
```

To change this to disabled textbox,

Use `replace` with the same regex.

```js
var string = "My name is ______ I live at ______.";

document.body.innerHTML += string.replace(/_{6}/g,'<input type="text" disabled />');
```

Comment: I am defining the string in my controller. then i defined a <p  id="q01">{{Question}}<p> tag  so that i can access it in my <script> tag.  But now i am not able to replace the underscores with textboxes

Comment: @Saniya how you're replacing the html?

Comment: Here is the code snippet:                                                                              <body>
    <h2> Fill in the blanks </h2>
   <p id="q01">{{fQuestion}}
       </p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var question = $("#q01").html();
    question.trim();
    question.split(/_{6}/g);
    console.log(question);
    $("#q01").text+=question.replace(/_{6}/g, '<input type="text" disabled="disabled">');
   // document.body.innerHTML += string.replace(/_{6}/g, '<input type="text" disabled />');
</script>

Comment: make a jsfiddle so that I can edit it there. it need some editing

Comment: I have edited my question but it gives error on {{fQuestion}} since it is defined in my controller

Comment: don't edit the question. It'll leave people confused. make a fiddle on jsfiddle.com  I rollbacked it.

Comment: @Saniya `{{variable}}` is not pure js. I edited a little. but it'll work with your compiler. Here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/sagarvd01/asmq8yno/

Comment: so you just replaced {{variable}} with string?

Comment: not only. you have to do many other things like `$().text` is not a variable. it's a function. but you have to use `$().html()` to make the input works

Comment: Got that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace the underscores with the wanted input.

```js
var string = 'My name is ______. I live at ______.';

document.body.innerHTML += string.replace(/_{6}/g, '<input type="text" disabled="disabled">');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a native .split() method to achieve this. Jus place your underscores as a parameter. But I believe your question will be downvoted because you could google it yourself very easily...

```
var myString = 'My name is ______ I live at ______';
myString.split('______');
```

Comment: you can use regex `/_{6}/g` instead of `______`

Comment: true... I didn't used it just to make it simplier to get how split function works.

Comment: @Redo I am defining the string in my controller. then i defined a <p  id="q01">{{Question}}<p> tag  so that i can access it in my <script> tag.  But now i am not able to replace the underscores with textboxes

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 string rec = "My name is ______I live at ______";
 string[] spliRes = rec.Split('_').Where(x => x.Length > 0).ToArray();
```

for disbaled textbox:

```
var record = "My name is ______ I live at ______."; 
document.body.innerHTML += record.replace(/_{6}/g,'<input type="text" disabled />');
```